# Orion Context Broker crashes when calling updateContext. It seems related to the subscriptions

Tags: fiware-orion

The Orion Context Broker crash when calling updateContext to entities which are registered to subscriptions.

The logs since the updateContext call until the segfault:

```
time=2014-10-23T12:34:50.527EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=1414082071-014-00000000001 | function=connectionTreat | comp=Orion | msg=rest.cpp[629]: Starting transaction from 179.148.168.28:52459/NGSI10/updateContext
time=2014-10-23T12:34:50.528EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=1414082071-014-00000000001 | function=processContextElement | comp=Orion | msg=MongoCommonUpdate.cpp[1518]: Database Operation Successful ({ _id.id: "AguasSaoPedro_Rua1_02", _id.type: "Lamp", _id.servicePath: { $exists: false } })
time=2014-10-23T12:34:50.546EDT | lvl=INFO | trans=1414082071-014-00000000001 | function=addTriggeredSubscriptions | comp=Orion | msg=MongoCommonUpdate.cpp[811]: Database Operation Successful ({ $or: [ { entities.id: "XXXX", $or: [ { entities.type: "Lamp" }, { entities.type: { $exists: false } } ], entities.isPattern: "false", conditions.type: "ONCHANGE", conditions.value: "intensity", expiration: { $gt: 1414082090 } }, { entities.isPattern: "true", conditions.type: "ONCHANGE", conditions.value: "intensity", expiration: { $gt: 1414082090 }, $where: function(){for (var i=0; i < this.entities.length; i++) {if (this.enti... } ] })
```

What could be wrong, or any suggestions to identify the problem?

Comment: could yo update your question in order to include the contextBroker version you are using, please? (i.e. the result of the `contextBroker --version` command)

Comment: Moreover, it would be also useful to include the exact updateContext message that you are issuing (along with any previous r̶e̶g̶i̶s̶t̶e̶r̶C̶o̶n̶t̶e̶x̶t̶ subscribeContext in place at CB) in order to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to identify what could be wrong I did:

- Removed all subscriptions. Since we make this server available for tests from partners there was more than 200 subscriptions
- Updated the CB (to 0.17 version, the current one installed)

I'm not sure if it was a old issue or if there were some broken subscription registered, but everything worked fine after that.